# How to install Wine / wireshark offline in an Ubntu box

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I need to install wireshark on my new offline Ubuntu 180.4 box. I understand that if we have wine then we can install windows Wireshark in Ubuntu and execute it.

If my understanding is correct I was searching site to download Wine first for Ubuntu (binary) into USB drive and then install it in my Ubuntu box. I landed up here -

http://wine.budgetdedicated.com/archive/binary/

But it has created confusion - now which .deb file I need to download as there are around 100s of them?

Comment: You can install WireShark in Ubuntu without Wine.

Comment: Please provide the steps to do so for an offline Ubuntu box ?

Comment: I am sorry but I am search of answer which I do not yet have

Comment: Link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/700712/